# Install QGIS LTR on Linux 16.04/Mint 18

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, linux-mint

I would like to install the current QGIS LTR (2.14.15) under Linux Mint 18. I have followed the QGIS instructions for installing the LTR from the ubuntugis ppa without success. I get the following error about unmet dependencies:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qgis : Depends: qgis-providers (= 1:2.14.15+24xenial) but 1:2.18.8+24xenial-ubuntugis is to be installed
 qgis-plugin-grass : Depends: qgis-plugin-grass-common (= 1:2.14.15+24xenial) but 1:2.18.8+24xenial-ubuntugis is to be installed
                     Depends: qgis-provider-grass (= 1:2.14.15+24xenial) but 1:2.18.8+24xenial-ubuntugis is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

I had previously used the LTR candide QGIS 2.18.x, but decided to replace with the LTR. I have removed and purged qgis and removed the related content from my sources.list file before attempting to install the LTR. I have also tried the steps listed in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191681/install-qgis-2-14-essen-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial). My errors still invoke 2.18.8. Can I install the LTR on Xenial, and if so, how do I do it?

**Edit:**  Here is the result of

```
apt-cache policy qgis-providers
```

below

```
qgis-providers:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:2.14.15+24xenial
  Version table:
     1:2.14.15+24xenial 500
        500 http://qgis.org/debian-ltr xenial/main amd64 Packages
     2.8.6+dfsg-1build1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: You may have missed `sudo apt-get update`. What do you get from `apt-cache policy qgis-providers` ?

Comment: The output of apt-cache policy looks good, no dependency on any 2.18.8 package. Can you install only that, then test the policy of the other packages in the error message the same way?

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa`
`sudo apt-get update` (or use Software Manager using the GUI) and set Synaptic Package Manager to Package -> Force Version