# How to reinstall QGIS from scratch on Ubuntu?

Tags: qgis, installation, error, ubuntu, repository

System info: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, kernel 4.10.0-33-generic

---

I was trying to update QGIS using [these](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/191689/30193) steps. For some reason, it broke in the process and I'm not able to start it anymore. Executing `qgis` gives me the following:

> /usr/bin/qgis.bin: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libqgis_core.so.2.14.17: undefined symbol: OGR_F_SetFieldNull

I didn't really know what to make of it, so I tried reinstalling the whole thing. Specifically running

```
sudo apt purge qgis* python-qgis* --auto-remove
sudo apt install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

However, at the end of the installation process I now get the messages:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis:
 qgis depends on qgis-providers (= 2.14.17+dfsg-1~xenial3); however:
  Package qgis-providers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up qgis-plugin-grass-common (2.14.17+dfsg-1~xenial3) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis-provider-grass:
 qgis-provider-grass depends on qgis (= 2.14.17+dfsg-1~xenial3); however:
  Package qgis is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis-provider-grass (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis-plugin-grass:
 qgis-plugin-grass depends on qgis (= 2.14.17+dfsg-1~xenial3); however:
  Package qgis is not configured yet.
 qgis-plugin-grass depends on qgis-provider-grass (= 2.14.17+dfsg-1~xenial3); however:
  Package qgis-provider-grass is not configured yet.

No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                                                        dpkg: error processing package qgis-plugin-grass (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 qgis-providers
 qgis
 qgis-provider-grass
 qgis-plugin-grass
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I then tried the same thing without the QGIS repositories, but with the same results, which is why I'm thinking there are still some broken leftovers from my previous attempts on my machine.

Is there any way to nuke my QGIS installation more thoroughly than by using `sudo apt purge qgis* python-qgis* --auto-remove`, so that absolutely nothing is left?

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25325513/getting-dependency-issues-on-configuring-dpkg

Comment: That's a good hint, thanks. The accepted answer doesn't work for me, though. But I'm guessing it's some dpkg-shenanigans that cause my problems.

Comment: Therefore I suggest to ask at stackoverflow or askubuntu.

Comment: Did just that. Link is https://askubuntu.com/questions/954699/how-to-fix-these-broken-package-dependencies if anyone wants to chip in.

Comment: I have the same problem on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. How did you solve it?

Comment: I'm not sure anymore, but I think I ended up reinstalling the operating system.

Comment: Here are some more useful hints: https://askubuntu.com/questions/716915/dpkg-error-processing-packages-cannot-complete-install-desktop-gui-from-termina

Answer (score 11):

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

there in the package manager remove qgis and ubuntugis from the list;

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get autoremove qgis
sudo apt-get --purge remove qgis

sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

this worked once for me,
in my trusty that installs qgis essen

Comment: I tried that now, but I still end up with the same lengthy dpkg error message as before.

Answer (score 3):

Run this code below to remove the application:

`sudo apt-get remove <application_name>`

Also, to uninstall all related packages AND configuration files, you can type

`sudo apt-get purge <package-name>`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I already did remove QGIS with `sudo apt purge qgis* python-qgis* --auto-remove`, but still ran into errors.